# Advanced routing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, routes

I am looking for a advanced routing solution in JavaScript. I have draw the following image:

[image: Routing]

Let say the user takes the following road in the application:

**A** -> **B** -> **E** -> **F**

To go back is very easy in javascript I use this line of code

`window.history.back();`

The road will be like this:

**F** -> **E** -> **B** -> **A**

Now I am searching for a solution that the user can navigate from **F** to **B** in one click.

**F** -> **B**

We can hardcode a button with the router link to it but this must be **dynamic** because we have 3 different pages. I have seen a lot of solutions and frameworks but the most are outdated.

How can I get the state from the routing so the user can go in one click to the specific page?

Comment: Angular has a powerful [router](https://angular.io/guide/router), and I'm pretty sure it's not yet outdated :)

Comment: The application I working on is Javascript. Angular is in typescript

Comment: This may be ignorant of me, but just call `window.history.back()` twice?
If the button is supposed to bring you back to the second page the user went to it should work.

Comment: The requirement is the user can do both. The user wants to go back to page **B** in one click. It depends on the path the user takes. 
**F** -> **B**
**F** -> **C**
**F** -> **D**

Comment: I dont think back routing will be useful in this case. Have you tried using `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState` ?

Comment: I am looking now at the documentation. I think `history.pushState` could be a solution with a few if statements.

Answer (score 1):

With React

You can use [**React-Router**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core), this library has a function for go to especifically page history.go(n) or if you want to use stack navigation  history.goBack() .

With Javascript DOM API

The history interface has similar functionality , if you want to navigate to specifically, you could use window.history.go(n)

Comment: Thanks for you time! We don't use reactjs or a framework for this application. That makes it hard to work on this problem. If we used frameworks it was already solved.  I was looking in **express.js** something like that.